# Access childrens using where condition for nested attributes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-attributes, accepts-nested-attributes

I have the following relationship set, dashboard filter values have a column called filter_type which can have value 1 or 0.

```
class DashboardFilterValue < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :dashboard_filter
end
```

```
class DashboardFilter < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :dashboard_filter_values, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :dashboard_filter_values
  before_save :check_parameter_length

  def check_parameter_length
    Rails.logger.info self.dashboard_filter_values.inspect #prints the ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy
    Rails.logger.info self.dashboard_filter_values.where(:filter_type => 0) #does not print anything
  end
end
```

In the `before_save` callback,
When I use `self.dashboard_filter_values.inspect`, this prints
`ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`.

But `self.dashboard_filter_values.where(:filter_type => 0)` **does not** print anything, even when there are records which satisfy the condition.

In the `before_save` callback, how can I use the where condition to filter values that I want.

Any help in this would be really great. Thanks.

Comment: Do you actually see anything in the `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy` or is it empty?

Comment: Hi @Trinculo, I do see data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is not working because of the `before_save` action.  When you use `where` it is performing a database query, but because you are querying the database before it saves, nothing is returned.

I would say you have 2 options:

1. Convert it to an `after_save`
2. Use `Enumerable#select` instead:

```
Rails.logger.info self.dashboard_filter_values.select { |filter| filter.filter_type == 1 }
```

Comment: Thanks @Trinculo, that makes sense. I will go with your approach 2, as i want to invalidate the records in case a condition fails. i think with after_create it would be a bit tricky.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean [`Enumerable#select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-select), not [`Enumerable#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-map). `dashboard_values.select { |dashboard_value| dashboard_value.filter_type == 0 }`

Comment: Yes, I ended up using select. Thanks for awesome help guys.